# Why does fess Sinu-Cleanse say not to use if your nasal passages are completely blocked

Tags: common-cold, nasal-congestion, saline

On the pack it says to not to use if the nasal passage is completely blocked. Can using it with a blocked nasal package cause harm and if so how?

[[image]